# How to guarantee and return unique ID in MySql with many users on one client

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id, ignition

So I'm working on a MySQL database with three tables:

Table 1 defines an fruit, with columns like "name", "color", "flavor" and "Fruit_ID".

Table 2 defines a category, with columns like "name", "description", and "Cat_ID".

Table 3 defines the relationship between fruit and category, with two columns, "Fruit_ID" and "Cat_ID".

Whenever a fruit is inserted, it must be correlated to a category using Table 3. My original plan was to make Fruit_ID and Cat_ID autoincrement and use [this method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html), but the problem is my architecture has multiple users sharing just one client connection, and LAST_INSERT_ID is only [guaranteed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21181/is-mysqls-last-insert-id-function-guaranteed-to-be-correct) to be correct for each client, afaik.

So my question is, what kind of SQL Query can I use to ensure that when a fruit is entered into Table 1, the correct Fruit_ID is used in Table 2 to categorize it?

Also, I'm open to restructuring my database if this isn't the best way to make this kind of association (I'm new to database architecture).

I'm not open to using stored procedures in SQL.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For the record, my database isn't actually about fruit, but fruit is such an easy example to use for this kind of thing...

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you have multiple users sharing just one client connection?

Comment: The queries will be made from Inductive Automation Ignition clients, which actually send the query text to a gateway with a pool of shared connections; there's no knowing which connection will be used by a given query. So technically, my question was inaccurately worded, but still there must be a solution for this kind of problem out there, I suspect.

Comment: Does this system allow sending multiple statements as one text? If yes, there is no problem. Just send the insert and the select LAST_INSERT_ID() as one compound statement.

Comment: So your statements are not running in a transaction?

Comment: I don't understand the problem with using last_insert_id

Comment: @NineBerry I can set up transactions, but maybe I don't understand the significance of multiple statements in a single transaction. In general, unless explicitly specified, transactions are automatically managed at the gateway.

Comment: I'll research the transaction option some more; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, you'll have to use a query to get the ID of the item you just inserted.

So to add a row that says apples are red, you do:

```
INSERT INTO fruit_category (fruit_id, cat_id)
SELECT f.id, c.id
FROM fruit AS f
CROSS JOIN category AS c
WHERE f.name = 'apple'
AND c.name = 'red'
```

This is the same thing you would do if you were creating this relationship and hadn't just added the rows.